# java documentation

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

i am not able to create documentation for this code,i think my coomad of javadoc is not right, i read about it but don't understand ,can anybody correct by javadoc cammand

```
class abc
{/** documentaion line 1
*
* */
public static void main(String a[])
{/** documentaion line 2
*
* */
System.out.println("documentation");
}
}
```

```
Error:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>javac abc.java

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>java abc
documentation

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>javadoc abc
Loading source files for package abc...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package abc
Constructing Javadoc information...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package abc
javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
1 error
2 warnings
```

Comment: **Did you read the error message**?

Answer (score 8):

In your case, you would want to provide the file name instead of a package name.

```
javadoc abc.java
```

Then the *no source files* error message will disappear.
The *no public classes* error message will still be there - add `public` before your class declaration. Alternatively, you can pass the `-package` or `-private` flag to Javadoc to include non-public classes too.

Then move the documentation comments directly before the declarations you want to comment:

```
/**
 * class documentation here
 */
public class abc
{

    /** 
     * method documentation here 
     */
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
      /**
       * this will be ignored.
       */
       System.out.println("documentation");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message clearly says, Javadoc creates documentation for `public` or `protected` classes and methods (members that are visible from outside your package).

You don't have any.

Also, Javadoc takes a **package** (folder or JAR file), not a classname.

Comment: The problem is not that it is not public, but that there are no source files in the **package**.

Answer (score 3):

This is old, I know, but I found a solution that worked for me. It isn't package based but it took me forever to figure it out so I figured I'd share it:

```
javadoc -private *.java
```

The private option is the key here.